# Exchanging OAuth2 Access token with user info

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, vert.x, kong

I'm trying to implement OAuth authentication for my application which consist of a frontend and bunch of microservices.

I'm plan to use - [kong](http://getkong.org) and it's my firstime implementing oAuth but wondering how do I exchange the access_token to get the user info ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Kong OAuth2 example](https://github.com/Mashape/kong-oauth2-hello-world).
I've followed this example and when the user authorize the App to access the data, I sent an User Identifier to Kong.

You can see it in the example [app.js #L75](https://github.com/Mashape/kong-oauth2-hello-world/blob/master/app.js#L75)

So the value of `authenticated_userid=$USER_ID` will be forwarded to the upstream in each request in the header `X-Authenticated-Userid`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have Kong already up and running.
Their guide to OAuth2 is pretty straightforward:

https://getkong.org/plugins/oauth2-authentication/

- Install OAuth2 plugin
- Create Consumer: this will be used by the calling microservice
- Create Application: this will be used by the called microservice

The ID of the consumer should be in X-Consumer-ID header when OAuth passes.

Comment: In the OAuth2Options you can specify the header that will be used when dealing with kong. https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/master/vertx-auth-oauth2/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/auth/oauth2/OAuth2ClientOptions.java#L191